# Thread local pyzmq ioloop

Tags: python, multithreading, tornado, pyzmq

I was wondering if there is a way to have a thread local ioloop in pyzmq.  The comment in the code says (https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/blob/master/zmq/eventloop/minitornado/ioloop.py line 172):

> In general you should use `IOLoop.current` as the default when
>           constructing an asynchronous object, and use `IOLoop.instance`
>           when you mean to communicate to the main thread from a different
>           one.

According to this I assume that using .current I should be able to create thread local ioloop which I can start/stop independently of the main thread ioloop.

Strangely, this is not the behavior that I observe (I use .current in the local thread, but doing .stop on this loop also stop main threads loop). Moreover, this simple test code:

```
import threading
from zmq.eventloop import ioloop

loop = ioloop.IOLoop.current()
print 'main id(loop):', id(loop)

class w(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, loop=None):
        super(w, self).__init__()

        self.loop = loop or ioloop.IOLoop.current()

        print 'w.__init__ id(loop):', id(self.loop)

    def run(self):
        print 'w.__run__ id(loop):', id(self.loop)
        print 'current:', id(ioloop.IOLoop.current())


w(loop).start()
```

prints the same ids for both loops:

```
main id(loop): 33576144
w.__init__ id(loop): 33576144
w.__run__ id(loop): 33576144
current: 33576144
```

I would be glad to understand what do I miss.

Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IOLoop.current()` has some quirks for historical reasons. It will refer to the thread-local event loop if one exists, but it will not create one, instead falling back to the singleton (main-thread) loop.

The solution is to create a new loop in `w.__init__()` (`self.loop = ioloop.IOLoop()`) and make it current in `w.run()` (`self.loop.make_current()`. `loop.start()` will call `make_current()` for you).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. BTW, isn't IOLoop a singleton class?

Comment: In the vast majority of cases there is only one IOLoop per process, but in some rare cases it's useful to have more than one.